# IFRAME with addEventListener and msFullscreenElement not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have 2 things with problems the first I have this:

```
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", function(){alert("Hello World3");}, false);
```

That checks if an iframe go to full screen in explorer. For example a page intro.html call an iframe inside of it then if that iframe go to full screen (like a video) then that line of code detects perfectly. If you hit go to full screen or resize intro.html does nothing and is ok that just detect the iframe full screen mode.
Now the problem is I want to make the opposite. Is there a way that like the line above check if NOT HAPPEN executes any code and if happens do nothing.

Second problem I have this code:

```
var isvarfull = document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null
var isnot = isvarfull.toString();
    if (!isnot)
    {
    alert('Fullscreenexecutefix ' + isnot)

    }
```

In google chrome and mozilla works perfectly. Suppose you have intro.html and that intro.html has an iframe then if you go to full screen from that iframe (like a video) DOES NOTHING (is what I want) and if you go to full screen or resize from intro.html execute this "alert('Fullscreenexecutefix ' + isnot)" and is ok both results. However this script does not work in explorer. Is there a way to make it work in explorer? I tried to add the value to check explorer condition:

```
var fullexplorer = document.msFullscreenElement !== null
```

And I checked with one "alert (fullexplorer);" And always show "true" no matter if you go to full screen or resize the intro.html or iframe. Then because of this of course like always is true I can't add a condition. what could be added to the script to make work on explorer?

Comment: "_always show "true"_" Yep, if it doesn't exist, `document.msFullscreenElement` will be `undefined`, which is not strictly equal to `null`.

Comment: Then what code you suggest to add?

Comment: How about comparing against `undefined`?

Comment: I did this "var fullexplorer = document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined" and give me all false results now.

Comment: Or is there a way in example 1 to use a code instead the alert to store a variable and that variable can be used outside the function addEventListener because if I use for example var xxx = "anyvalue" the value is not stored in the next lines of code just inside addEventListener. This is the example 1 I mention: "Or if there is a way in example 1 to put a variable: "document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", function(){alert("Hello World3");}, false);" This works perfect but I miss a variable to be used in later code. Once having a variable I can use anything in next lines of code.